Error in React.js run:"npm start" -> [eslint] EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/mac/Desktop/my-app/node_modules/.cache'
I use macOS, I run the code in React.js npm start after creating the app. In the browser window opens in localhost:3000 and then displays the error
[eslint] EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/mac/Desktop/my-app/node_modules/. cache'

